# Apache beam, FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP is deprecated?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have code in my apache beam 2.2.0 pipeline which is responsible for writing a json file to Google Cloud Storage. The code is as follows:

```
results.apply(ParDo.of(new TableRowToString()))
        .apply("WriteProfile", TextIO.write().to(outputBucket)
            .withWritableByteChannelFactory(FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP)
            .withNumShards(numChunks));
```

While looking at the code in Eclipse, I noticed it was giving me a warning over the text *FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP*:

> The field FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP is deprecated

What is the recommended way of writing gzipped files to GCS, and if this is documented elsewhere (apache beam docs, SO) what is the link to that documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With beam 2.2.0 I am not aware of an alternative way to write compressed data to Google Cloud Storage.

In beam 2.3.0+ they recommend using the newer `FileIO` API.

[FileIO 2.4.0 Docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html)

With the new `FileIO` API it is as simple as appending the `withCompression` call to your `FileIO` chain.

```
FileIO.write().to("gs://bucket/path").withCompression(Compression.GZIP);
```

If you cannot update and *really* want to avoid the deprecation you can implement the factory yourself, but that is exactly what `FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP` already does.

```
TextIO.write().to("gs://bucket/path").withWritableByteChannelFactory(new FileBasedSink.WritableByteChannelFactory() {
    @Override
    public WritableByteChannel create(final WritableByteChannel channel) throws IOException {
        return Compression.GZIP.writeCompressed(channel);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getMimeType() {
        return MimeTypes.BINARY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getSuggestedFilenameSuffix() {
        return Compression.GZIP.getSuggestedSuffix();
    }
});
```